# How do i put a button that clicks into a new View that is not clickable by one of the Tab Bar Items?

Tags: iphone

i set up a tab bar application and am having problems.

I wanna add 1 button in the "First View" that clicks into another view(that is not available from the tab bar item)

but am having problems..

What code do i put into FirstViewController.h and .m?

Do i have to create a new xib file?

Comment: oh, i didn't know that it is possible to add subView to the "First View" of the tab bar application... so basically what i want is this: I'm in the first view of a tab bar application, and i want to go into another view that is not on tab bar by clicking a button.. Thank you so much so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I'm not sure I've understood you right, but you can just creating new view in the button click method and add is as a subView to your self.view. Add some more comments about wat correctrly you want and I'll post some code.

Comment: oh, i didn't know that it is possible to add subView to the "First View" of the tab bar application... so basically what i want is this: I'm in the first view of a tab bar application, and i want to go into another view that is not on tab bar by clicking a button.. Thank you so much so much!!!!